# Search and replace with regex including lookbehinds does not work in VS2017

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio-2017, lookbehind, find-replace

In Visual Studio 2017, I am trying to turn some lines like this :

```
[AddressId] [int] NOT NULL,
[CountryId] [int] NULL,
[POBoxCountryId] [int] NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar] (100) NULL,
```

into this :

```
[AddressId] int NOT NULL,
[CountryId] int NULL,
[POBoxCountryId] int NULL,
[Name] nvarchar (100) NULL,
```

It seems to me that the regex : `(?<=\[\w+\]\s)\[(\w+)\]` Should exactly match the second pairs of brackets, and capture what's inside.

And it seems this is actually the case when I examine it in RegexStorm : [regexstorm link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%5Cw%2B%5C%5D%5Cs%29%5C%5B%28%5Cw%2B%29%5C%5D&i=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BAddressId%5D%20%5Bint%5D%20NOT%20NULL%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BCountryId%5D%20%5Bint%5D%20NULL%2C%0D%0A%09%20%5BPOBoxCountryId%5D%20%5Bint%5D%20NULL%2C%0D%0A%09%20%5BName%5D%20%5Bnvarchar%5D%20%28100%29%20NULL%2C)

Also, in Visual Studio, I can see that it is correctly found as well if I do a *find*. The lines where there is a match are displayed.

---

However, if I try to do a *find and replace* (replace by `$1`), no replacement is done. (the replacement is working in regexStorm)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try `(\[\w+]\s+)\[(\w+)]` and replace with `$1$2`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works fine, thanks ! So does this mean I should not use lookbehinds when doing find & replace in VS ?

Comment: They are supported by the .NET regex engine, no idea what exactly happened here. Capturing groups are safer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll try to create a bug report to MS to see if it is a problem in VS. Too bad, it broke my plans to do one big regex to do several operations in one go I guess will have to apply different regexps in chain, then.

Comment: Let me know what kind of a regex you have in mind, I have VS2017, and might help.

Comment: It is really weird that the lookbehind based regex matches but does not replace.

Answer (score 3):

You may  use

**Find What**: `(\[\w+]\s+)\[(\w+)]`
**Replace With**: `$1$2`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qfQYM1/1/)

**Details**

- `(\[\w+]\s+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `[`, 1+ word chars, `]` and 1+ whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(\w+)`   - Group 2 (`$2`): 1+ word chars
- `]` -  a `]` char.